# How do I supress the popups between authentication in webviews

Tags: android, android-webview

I have created an authenticated webview, which allows user to search using a keyword to display the content in the webview. However the webview has authentication set on each and every page, so if i navigate within the webview, i have to authenticate again, which in my case i used the sharedprefs manager to remember loginname and password which authenticates it automatically. However, every time i navigate to a different page within the webview, it pops up a screen asking "You have been signed out,because you logged into another device [cancel|sign in] "How do I stop this alert message from showing in my authenticated webview, which is clearly happening due to authentication. I am using cookies, but I am not sure If i am using them the right way. Here's a sneak peak of my code:

```
 public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        private String loginCookie;
        public MyWebViewClient(AnswersWebViewFragment answersWebViewFragment, WebView webview) {
            super();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setCookie(url, loginCookie);
            final Animation fade = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            fade.setDuration(200);
            view.startAnimation(fade);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError( WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl ) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Authentication Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource( WebView view, String url ){
            //CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            //loginCookie = cookieManager.getCookie(url);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);


        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError( WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error ) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest( WebView view, final HttpAuthHandler handler, final String host, final String realm ){


                handler.proceed(USERNAME,PASSWORD);

    }


    }
```

and in other class here's how i store username and pass:

```
SharedPreferencesManager manager = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance();
    private static  String URL;
    private final  String USERNAME = manager.getLoginUsername();
    private final  String PASSWORD = manager.getDecryptedLoginPassword();
```

any idea how to go about the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out the code that authenticates the login in the search page